# ASUS Zenith Extreme - Wake on LAN not working from android

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan

I cannot find anything relating to this specific motherboard. The **ASUS Zenith Extreme**.

Here's what I've tried so far. If anyone owns this motherboard and got WOL working then please let me know if I missed out on any steps.

1. I have the latest [bios update Version 2001](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-ZENITH-EXTREME/HelpDesk_Download/) for **Windows 10 18363**.
2. Have the latest drivers for my onboard **Intel(R) I211 Gigabit** with IP shown in the screenshots below `192.168.1.89`.
3. Enabled the **Power On By PCI-E/PCI** in the BIOS.

   [image]
4. Disabled the fast boot in the BIOS.
5. Enabled these settings in the adapter card settings in Device Manager:

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
6. **Power Options**

   [image]
   [image]
7. **WakeMeOnLan utility** from [Nir Sofer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html)

   This shows all the devices in green meaning that they're all on, in which case this is correct.

   From here, I know that the values are correct to enter into the app from the play store.

   [image: WakeMeOnLan]
8. I then downloaded this from the Play Store. [Wake on LAN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.mrwebb.wakeonlan&hl=en) and entered the same values but it won't wake the PC and the app shows no green overlay to show that it's on like how WakeMeOnLan shows.

   [image]
9. I've also download WakeOnLAN https://wol.aquilatech.com/ and entered in the exact same details there and managed to restart my PC using that, although this was installed on the same machine as I was restarting. But this tells me that it can work but getting it to work with any mobile app isn't working out.

---

Any help here would be great to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Have you turned on Simple TCPIP services?

  **Control Panel** > **Simple TCPIP services** > **Turn Windows features on or off** > Check '**Simple TCPIP services**' > **OK**
- Your router may require special permission to allow this feature.
- Open Powershell with admin rights:

  **SUPER + X** > **A**

  Run `REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 0 /F`
- In your network adapter card properties in its advanced settings, enable the **Enable PME** option.

[Source](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?101283-Wake-on-LAN-not-working-from-shutdown-Asus-Deluxe-Z170#post714468)

Answer (score 0):

I followed guide (quite long, so not cited here: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045950/ )
and I see your steps not include simple "Allow this device to wake computer".

Try this and get back. But I bet this is dead thread nevertheless.

BTW. on my old laptop this was bread and butter to set up. On new MoBo it is pain like yours :D

[image showing exact option copied from ASUS page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk9Ke.png)